# HTML.ActionLink querystring param not passed to method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Examining some code, don't see why this fails.  The primary controller's index method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int appEventId = -1)
```

There normally isn't a querystring param, but occasionally there's a need to route to the main page and pass a particular ID to auto-display. The default value of -1 indicates that it should display normally.  This works fine normally.

In another page, this razor code generates a valid hyperlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Main", "Index", "MainController", new { appEventId = -9 }, new { }) // certain things renamed to protect the innocent!
```

When testing locally this works like a charm.  The controller Index method detects -9 as a particular value and does something for that specific case.

However, when deployed on a web server, the application is in a subfolder, not the root. Mostly it works fine, but in the above case, it generates the url like this:

```
http://server/appSubFolder/?appEventId=-9
```

And the above URL looks correct, but the controller's Index method is not passed the -9.

Is there some limitation that an MVC app cannot be deployed to a subfolder?  I'm not the one who decided to deploy it this way, I'm just trying to make sense of the error.

Comment: Are you using IIS as the web server?  Should be able to tell it/configure it to use the subfolder as the root of the application.

Comment: Already raised that, but there's some red tape involved.  Meanwhile, this should work, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still think this is a bug with MVC, or at least it should be clearer that it's not a best practice to set the site up this way.

But, for anyone who may be interested, I worked around this problem by replacing the @Html.ActionLink with the following:

```
<a href='@Url.Content("~/Controller/Index?appEventId=-9")'>Back To Main</a>
```

This avoids shortening the /Controller/Method style of url to just "/" when it's the main controller's Index method, and thus the querystring is parsed correctly and passed to the Index() method.